# iOS Push Notifications with NodeJS - credentials

Tags: ios, node.js, push-notification, engineyard, apnagent

I have a requirement to implement the server side code for pushing notifications to an iOS app. I have followed [this link](https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/developing-ios-push-notifications-nodejs).

The problem is I always get 'Insufficient credentials' message. I am using the `apnagent` node module.

Has anyone tried this successfully? Is there something additional I should do to set my credentials?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I just got apnagent running. Assuming you set up your certificate and app correctly, I got it to work with either:

- certificate.p12 and passphrase, *or*
- cert.pem and key.pem files

That is:

```
agent
    .set('cert file', join(__dirname, '../_cert/apn-dev-cert.pem'))
    .set('key file', join(__dirname, '../_cert/apn-dev-key.pem'))
    //or this works too:
    // .set('pfx file', join(__dirname, '../_cert/Certificates.p12'))
    // .set('passphrase', 'your passphrase')
    .enable('sandbox')
```